# C++ Exception thrown: Access violation writing

Tags: c++

> Exception thrown at 0x008F1D0D in whileLTestStr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00770000.

This error comes up during runtime when trying to put one character from one array, into another array.

The error occurs right after inputting the string, it does not close the program, just "pauses" it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    char test[20];
    char result[20];
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Enter a string without symbolic characters: ";
    cin.get(test, 20);

    for (i; (test[i] != '?' || test[i] != '\0'); i++)
    {
        result[i] = test[i];    //Exception gets thrown here
    }

    if (strcmp(result, test) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Fail.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << result << endl;
        cout << "Success.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've marked out where the exception gets thrown with a comment.

This program is just for limiting what the user can enter, purely for testing. But I don't understand why this doesn't work.

There is probably some function to do this for me, but I'm still learning the language, and I'm just interested in trying and testing what I can do with the loops etc.

**EDIT**

After a suggestion I changed the OR operator for the AND operator, and I no longer get the error. However, I do get some really odd behavior.

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVody.png)

Comment: It's C++, use std::string!

Comment: @manni66 Haven't gotten so far into the language yet where I know how to look at each character of a string and do what I've done here, but I get your point

Comment: You look at each character of a string exactly like you do it. And a string has a size(), so you can use that in the for loop.

Comment: `char result[20] = {};` will fix the _really odd behavior_. Again: use std::string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test[i] != '?' || test[i] != '\0'` is always `true`, so you end up running past the bounds of the array, as `i++` increments too far.

Did you want an `&&` instead, in place of the `||`?

Finally, you need to insert an explicit NUL-terminator to `result`, else the output will be undefined. A simple way to do that is to initialise the array to an array of `\0`s using

```
char result[20] = {};
```

Comment: That was probably the cause of the error yes, thank you. However, something really strange happened when I did this, please look at the updated question

Comment: Also (and arguably more importantly), when you know ahead of time that both buffers are 20 characters long, you need to check that in your "for" conditions as well.  Whatever character are entered, you don't just keep incrementing "i".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string test;

    cout << "Enter a string without symbolic characters: ";
    getline(cin, test);

    if (test.find("?") != string::npos )
    {
        cout << "Fail.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << test << endl;
        cout << "Success.";
    }
}
```

That's how you can do it with std::string. Learn C++, not C.

Comment: Like mentioned, I'm fairly new and following a text book, so I was going through how to do it with char, and got a little ahead of the book. But this was useful, thanks